# Ambiguous exception using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Is there a way around this issue?

Take the following code...

```
namespace ReflectionResearch
{
 class Program
 {
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   Child child = new Child();

   child.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
  }
 }

 public class Parent
 {
  public string Name
  {
   get;
   set;
  }
 }

 public class Child : Parent
 {
  public new int Name
  {
   get;
   set;
  }
 }
}
```

The line 'child.GetType().GetProperty("Name")' throws b/c Name is ambiguous between Parent and Child.  I want "Name" from Child.  Is there a way to do this?

I tried various binding flags with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add some `BindingFlags`:

```
child.GetType().GetProperty("Name",
     BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

`DeclaredOnly` means:

> Specifies that only members declared at the level of the supplied type's hierarchy should be considered. Inherited members are not considered.

Or an alternative using LINQ (which makes it easy to add any unusual checks, for example checking `Attribute.IsDefined`):

```
child.GetType().GetProperties().Single(
    prop => prop.Name == "Name" && prop.DeclaringType == typeof(Child));
```